# Indicator species plot (Bubble plot with categorical axes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

New to ggplot2/R so id really appreciate someone to shed some light on creating a bubble plot for two categorical axes `Species` (Y) across different sites `North`, `South`, `East`, `West`,`North.east`,`Northwest`,`South.west`,`South.east` (X). The values listed here are indicator values that are relative to sites/species. 
Also - how can I determine what value range = size of the bubble? eg. values =0.8-0.9 = largest size..

Sample Data

```
structure(list(Species = c(13359L, 12867L, 11646L, 13214L, 11413L, 
3413L, 13249L, 11374L, 13267L, 2059L, 12941L, 13123L, 1904L, 
13252L, 12915L, 12749L, 11577L, 995L), North = c(0.94, 0, 0.9, 
0, 0.88, 0.87, 0, 0, 0.86, 0, 0.84, 0.83, 0.83, 0, 0, 0.82, 0.82, 
0.81), South = c(0, 0.92, 0.9, 0, 0.88, 0, 0.87, 0.87, 0.86, 
0.86, 0.84, 0.83, 0, 0.82, 0, 0.82, 0.82, 0), West = c(0, 0.92, 
0.9, 0, 0.88, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.86, 0.86, 0.84, 0, 0.83, 0.82, 
0, 0.82, 0.82, 0), East = c(0, 0.92, 0.9, 0, 0, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 
0, 0.86, 0.84, 0, 0, 0.82, 0, 0.82, 0.82, 0), North.east = c(0, 
0.92, 0.9, 0, 0.88, 0.87, 0.87, 0.87, 0.86, 0.86, 0, 0.83, 0, 
0.82, 0, 0, 0.82, 0.81), Northwest = c(0, 0, 0, 0.88, 0, 0.87, 
0.87, 0.87, 0, 0.86, 0.84, 0, 0, 0.82, 0, 0, 0, 0), South.west = c(0, 
0.92, 0.9, 0.88, 0.88, 0, 0.87, 0, 0.86, 0.86, 0.84, 0.83, 0, 
0, 0, 0.82, 0.82, 0), South.east = c(0, 0.92, 0.9, 0, 0.88, 0, 
0, 0.87, 0.86, 0, 0.84, 0.83, 0.83, 0, 0, 0.82, 0.82, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df %>%
    gather(Direction, Value, -Species) %>%
    mutate(
        Species = as.factor(Species),
        Orientation = as.factor(Direction)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Direction, Species)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = Value))
```

[image]

For setting the range, take a look at `scale_size`, `scale_radius` and `scale_size_area`.

Comment: Yes thank you!
Is there a way to reorder the directions on the x axis?

Comment: @ElleBlank Sure, you just have to reorder the `factor` levels accordingly. So for example, to reverse the order you'd replace `Species = as.factor(Species)` with `Species = factor(Species, sort(unique(Species), decreasing = T))`.

Comment: Hi again. How could I change the colour of different species? 
eg. 13359,13267,13249 = red, 995, 1094, 3413= blue etc? thank you